Salesforce Data Cloud Triggered Flow Not Triggering on Data Model Object (DMO) Insert/Update
I am experiencing an issue where my Salesforce Data Cloud flow is not being triggered as expected when a record is created or updated in the Data Cloud Data Model Object (DMO). Despite verifying multiple configurations and running debug logs, the flow does not activate, although it runs successfully during debugging.
Context:

Salesforce Environment: I am using Salesforce Data Cloud and Salesforce Service Cloud.
Flow Configuration: The flow in Service Cloud is a "Data Cloud Triggered Flow" and is set to trigger on record creation or update in a specific Data Model Object (DMO).
Flow Activation: The flow is active and has no errors during debugging.

I am using the Streaming API to inject records into my configured data stream, which in turn is mapped to my custom data model. As expected, after a couple of minutes, the record is correctly added to the DMO, which I can verify via Data Explorer. I can also select all records during flow debugging to see whether any issues would occur if the flow were to trigger based on that record. However, nothing happens.
I tried activating debug logs for the default workflow user, but no records of the flow being triggered/run are recorded. We have the Enterprise edition, and I can see that data cloud target and data action being created, which we're currently limited to three of, and that's fine.
For now, I've configured the flow to create a record of a custom object I created to complete a POC. Later on, my use case is aimed at sending an email to a contact whenever a new record is created or updated in my DMO. I've exhausted every documentation, video, error and trial, and also already contacted Salesforce support, but they're not sure yet either. I wanted to see if someone from the community has some common errors or troubleshooting tips.
Also good to know: I've been using copy field enrichments for a while, and it works fine. Therefore, I can safely assume that my setup and permissions are correct, although I've already gone ahead and tried to enable as much as possible for the two permission sets assigned responsible for the integration between Service Cloud and Data Cloud.
Despite all these checks, the flow still does not trigger when a record is inserted or updated in the DMO. The debug logs show no errors, and the flow runs successfully during debugging, but it does not activate as expected during actual record operations.
Questions:

Are there any additional configurations or settings I might be missing that could prevent the flow from triggering?
Could there be specific Salesforce Data Cloud constraints or considerations that affect flow triggers on DMOs?
Is there a more detailed way to debug or trace the flow trigger events in Salesforce Data Cloud?
Has anyone encountered a similar issue and found a solution or workaround?

Any insights or suggestions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
